# Unable to connect to the samba server

Tags: samba

I setup a samba server (`Version 3.6.9-167.el6_5`).
One of the sub folder contains more than one thousand, if I delete this folder then I can connect to the server, otherwise I am getting a timeout error (`NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT`). How can I prevent this error? Is it scanning the whole file system during connection?

Answer (score 0):

Someone reporting the same problem as yourself in this thread titled: [Samba NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT [solved]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173347) reported the following fixed their issue:

#### /etc/smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = METRAN
    encrypt passwords = yes
    wins support = yes
    log level = 1 
    max log size = 1000
    read only = no
[homes] 
    browsable = no
    map archive = yes
[printers] 
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = yes
    min print space = 2000
[test]
    browsable = yes
    read only = yes
    path = /usr/local/samba/tmp
```

Comment: Which part of that file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT transferring large files with a slow windows-2000 samba share over a slow network connection.

The error would not occur after reducing the buffer size, for example to 8192:
An example from the command line:

```
smbclient //192.168.0.2/spool -b 8192 -c "put bigfile.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

What filesystem do you have here ?
Could you try mounting filesystem as read only

Try changing

```
\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\
```

to higher value (for timeouts)